# Missing Schema for WordPress theme.json

Tags: json, wordpress, wordpress-theming, schema, jsonschema

According to the [docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/themes/theme-json/#developing-with-theme-json), one can simple add

```
$schema": "https://schemas.wp.org/trunk/theme.json",
```

to the beginning of the JSON file to load the schema

VS code gives me the error that it's missing:

[image: vs code error]

And sure enough, going to https://schemas.wp.org/trunk/theme.json it doesn't exist:

[image: site missing]

I've seen posts such as [this one about missing schema](https://make.wordpress.org/themes/2021/11/30/theme-json-schema/) which says to go to https://schemas.wp.org/wp/5.9/theme.json but same result. Searching around it seems like their security certificate expired at some point, but surely they resolved that many months ago.

I'd like to resolve this to get the benefits of schema (autocomplete / intellisense) in the file, especially since the file is getting larger and this is a large project with multiple people working on it.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like `https://schemas.wp.org/trunk/theme.json` is not reachable for you even though it is online (I can reach the URL). The url forwards to https://raw.githubusercontent.com/WordPress/gutenberg/trunk/schemas/json/theme.json, where the actual JSON file is located, which might be accessible for you. If yes, you can add this direct url as the value for `$schema`.

Comment: That was it, thanks! Must be VPN being dumb or something. Solved.

Answer (score 0):

Access the URL: "https://schemas.wp.org/trunk/theme.json" using VPN, It worked for me.

Copy the whole JSON and create a JSON file locally and use it as a reference.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).